# How could I sync Data between iWatch and iPhone app

Tags: ios, synchronization, watch

I want to create an ios app with iwatch extension. My app contains a few simple variables which I want to store and update during the day. Tried to share data using UserDefault - it's not working. Tried using Core Data database - don't understand is it possible to connect Core Data to Target Watch App for iOS. Same thing with Realm. Show me, please the correct direction!

Comment: Use a `application group identifier` and place the core-data db in that same group. You'll be able to share the db with the watch and any other extensions.

Comment: I've added to the group my ios and iwatch targets. Don't understand how to place the  core-data db in that same group? And now I checked - the color of a group is red. Does it mean I should buy Development Program? And I can't use it free?

Comment: I don't know if it's available for free accounts but I do know you need this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups

If your core-data db is created in the group location via: `FileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:"com.whatever.group.id")` then your watch can load it. See: https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-shared-coredata-storage-for-app-groups-447b4ba43eec

Comment: Tried using UserDefaults. When I write on iPHONE using `var sharedDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myGroup")
sharedDefault?.set(textFieldOne.text, forKey: "shared1")
print(UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myGroup")!.string(forKey: "shared1")!)
sharedDefault?.synchronize()`   AND try read it on WATCH `UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myGroup").sharedDefault!.string(forKey: "shared1")
textField.setText(sharedText)` i got a nil! The plist file does exist on Iphone (../Preferences/myGroup.plist) but NOT on watch! When I copy it manually - it works! But I cant do the same on real devices...